# Why does Mathematica try to take the first element of the empty list when plotting?

Tags: plotting, labeling

I'm using Mathematica 12.1.1.0.

When I enter

```
ListPlot[{{{1500, 4}, {1510, 4}, {1520, 4}, {1850, 6}}, {{1500, 
    1}, {18100, 1}}}, PlotLabels -> {"a", "b"}, Joined -> True, 
 PlotRange -> Full]
```

I get

```
Part::partw: Part 1 of {} does not exist.
Callout::copos: {19382.2,0.733053} is not a valid position for the placement of callouts.
```

[image]

What's going on here?  How do I avoid getting these error messages?

Edit: I've also emailed Wolfram Support about this, with ID [CASE:4760915].  I'll post any updates they give.  I'm still interested in a workaround.

Comment: Can't reproduce in _12.2.0_, _win 10_, looks like a (already fixed) bug.

Comment: It seems to be fixed in 12.2.0 on macOS as well, though I do get the error on 12.1.1 macOS as well. Hopefully someone will be able to offer a workaround.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a workaround

```
$Version

"12.1.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2020)"

data = {{{1500, 4}, {1510, 4}, {1520, 4}, {1850, 6}}, {{1500, 1}, {18100, 1}}};

labels = {"a", "b"};

Show[
 ListPlot[#[[1]],
    PlotStyle -> ColorData[97][#[[2]]],
    PlotLabels -> #[[3]],
    Joined -> True] & /@
  Transpose[{data, Range[Length[data]], labels}],
 PlotRange -> All,
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
Show[
 ListPlot[#1, 
    PlotStyle -> ColorData[97][#2], 
    PlotLabels -> #3, 
    Joined -> True] & @@@ 
  Transpose[{data, Range[Length[data]], labels}], 
 PlotRange -> All, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

Answer (score 5):

I am using V12.1.1.0 on MacOS 10.13.4 and I can reproduces your problem. I found the following work-around:

```
ListPlot[
  {Callout[
     {{1500, 4}, {1510, 4}, {1520, 4}, {1850, 6}}, 
       "a", {{2500, 6}, {0, .5}}, {2100, 6}],
   Callout[{{1500, 1}, {18100, 1}}, "b"]},
   Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: plot]

The work-around requires giving up the easy-to-use `PlotLabels` option and placing a callout wrapper around the 1st dataset, so the excellent micromanaging capabilities provided by `Callout` can be used.